# How can I GET a subset of appointments from a FHIR server?

Tags: json, postman, hl7-fhir

I'm retrieving JSON objects from a FHIR server that use this [template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFCS6.png). They look like this:

```
  "resourceType": "Appointment",
  "id": "example",
  "text": {
    "status": "generated",
    "div": "\u003cdiv xmlns\u003d\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"\u003eBrian MRI results discussion\u003c/div\u003e"
  },
  "status": "booked",
  "serviceCategory": [
    {
      "coding": [
        {
          "system": "http://example.org/service-category",
          "code": "gp",
          "display": "General Practice"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "serviceType": [
    {
      "coding": [
        {
          "code": "52",
          "display": "General Discussion"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "specialty": [
    {
      "coding": [
        {
          "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
          "code": "394814009",
          "display": "General practice"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "appointmentType": {
    "coding": [
      {
        "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0276",
        "code": "FOLLOWUP",
        "display": "A follow up visit from a previous appointment"
      }
    ]
  },
  "reasonReference": [
    {
      "reference": "Condition/example",
      "display": "Severe burn of left ear"
    }
  ],
  "priority": 5,
  "description": "Discussion on the results of your recent MRI",
  "start": "2013-12-10T09:00:00Z",
  "end": "2013-12-10T11:00:00Z",
  "created": "2013-10-10",
  "comment": "Further expand on the results of the MRI and determine the next actions that may be appropriate.",
  "basedOn": [
    {
      "reference": "ServiceRequest/myringotomy"
    }
  ],
  "participant": [
    {
      "actor": {
        "reference": "Patient/example",
        "display": "Peter James Chalmers"
      },
      "required": "required",
      "status": "accepted"
    },
    {
      "type": [
        {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-ParticipationType",
              "code": "ATND"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "actor": {
        "reference": "Practitioner/example",
        "display": "Dr Adam Careful"
      },
      "required": "required",
      "status": "accepted"
    },
    {
      "actor": {
        "reference": "Location/1",
        "display": "South Wing, second floor"
      },
      "required": "required",
      "status": "accepted"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "tag": [
      {
        "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-ActReason",
        "code": "HTEST",
        "display": "test health data"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This resource is an appointment and I would like to get all the appointments that have a particular actor, all of a specific patient's or doctor's appointments. The individual participants are nested a few layers in the JSON object. I don't know how to do a GET request on these nested elements.

Can I do a GET request to get this subset of appointments? Or is the usual practice to get all the appointments and filter them myself?

Comment: postman can only call what your API exposes. If you expose this API you can do it, if you don't - you cannot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the search options to filter the results of your FHIR query.  The parameters you can use to filter Appointment are listed [here](https://hl7.org/fhir/appointment.html#search) and the rules around crafting a search are found [here](http://hl7.org/fhir/search.html)

For example:

```
[base]/Appointment?actor=Patient/123&status=booked&date=ge2020-07-23
```

would give you all scheduled future appointments for the patient that are 'booked' (i.e. confirmed) from today onward.  The result would be a Bundle resource with a bunch of entries.  Each entry would contain an Appointment instance.

Comment: The links were pretty useful. Thanks!